# React-vertical-timeline is not showing. The output HTML keeps the elements hidden with "is-hidden" class

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-library

I am trying to implement a vertical timeline on my project. But its not showing on the generated HTML code. When I tried to inspect it, I see that the classes are generated to be hidden with "is-hidden". I think it might be having issues with intersection observer.

**timeline.js file**

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import SectionHeading from "./section-heading";
import {
  VerticalTimeline,
  VerticalTimelineElement,
} from "react-vertical-timeline-component";
import "react-vertical-timeline-component/style.min.css";
import { timelineData } from "@/lib/data";
import { useSectionInView } from "@/lib/hooks";

export default function Experience() {
  const { ref } = useSectionInView("Timeline");

  return (
    <section
      id="timeline"
      ref={ref}
      className="scroll-mt-28 mb-28 sm:mb-40 text-center"
    >
      <SectionHeading>Timeline</SectionHeading>
      <VerticalTimeline lineColor="">
        {timelineData.map((item, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={index}>
            <VerticalTimelineElement
              contentStyle={{
                background: "rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.05)",
                boxShadow: "none",
                border: "1px solid rgba(0, 230, 0, 0.05)",
                textAlign: "left",
                padding: "1.3rem 2rem",
              }}
              contentArrowStyle={{
                borderRight: "0.4rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)",
              }}
              date={item.date}
              icon={item.icon}
              iconStyle={{
                background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)",
                fontSize: "1.5rem",
              }}
            >
              <h3 className="font-semibold capitalize">{item.title}</h3>
              <p className="font-normal !mt-0">{item.location}</p>
              <p className="!mt-1 !font-normal text-gray-700 dark:text-white/75">
                {item.description}
              </p>
            </VerticalTimelineElement>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </VerticalTimeline>
    </section>
  );
}
```

## data.js file

````
  {
    index_number: 1,
    title: "Bachelor's Degree",
    location: "Bangladesh",
    description:
      "I completed my Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science and Software Engineering at the American International University-Bangladesh.",
    tags: ["CSSE", "Bachelors", "Graduation"],
    date: "2-September-1994",
    icon: <BiSolidGraduation />,
  },
  {
    index_number: 1,
    title: "Bachelor's Degree",
    location: "Bangladesh",
    description:
      "I completed my Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science and Softwarelre asjdajs.",
    tags: ["CSSE", "Bachelors", "Graduation"],
    date: "11-September-2021",
    icon: <BiSolidGraduation />,
  },```
````

Answer (score 3):

Same issue here, they get assigned an `is-hidden` CSS class by default.

I've added a `visible={true}` to the VerticalTimeline to fix the issue temporarily, but I think by default it should be set to true.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. While your edit did provide an answer, your original post did not and shouldn't have been presented as an answer. Also, no need to denote edits. Just update your answer.

Comment: Thanks man, that actually worked for me -- adding `visible` to `VerticalTimelineElement` <3

Comment: That works and displays the `<VerticalTimelineElement>`, but it doesn't animate the elements as you scroll down and the component enters the viewport by intersection observer's default prop `intersectionObserverProps={{ rootMargin: "0px 0px 120px 0px" }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Animation is the problem. I guess `VerticalTimelineElement` starts as hidden first and then changes status, but somehow that signal doesn't get detected or so.

To solve this for now you simply need to disable animation `<VerticalTimeline animate={false}>`

I hope they fix this soon. I really like the animation.

Answer (score 0):

please go to `VerticalTimelineElement` and add `visible={true}`